# How to check if an object has keys that are in an array?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of strings and I want to check if the object has all properties  that are in this array.

I could do a for loop and use `.hasOwnProperty()` but I want a better and smaller way to do it. I tried things like `.includes` , `var v in obj`, passing an array to `.hasOwnProperty` but nothing seems to work.

```
const obj = {Password: '123456', Username: 'MeMyselfAndI'}
const checkFields= ['Method', 'Password', 'Username']
return checkIfObjectHaveKeysOfArray(obj, checkFields) // should return false because object doesn't have property 'Method'
```

**Is there a way to do that without using a for loop? If yes, how?**

Comment: So loop over the keys with every...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I could do a for loop and use .hasOwnProperty() but I wan't a better and smaller way to do it

Loops aren't that big. :-) But you could use [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) with an arrow function:

```
return checkFields.every(key => obj.hasOwnProperty(key));
```

Live Example:

```js
const obj = {Password: '123456', Username: 'MeMyselfAndI'}
const checkFields= ['Method', 'Password', 'Username']
const result = checkFields.every(key => obj.hasOwnProperty(key));
console.log(result); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Object.hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) and check every key.

```js
const
    object = { Password: '123456', Username: 'MeMyselfAndI' },
    checkFields = ['Method', 'Password', 'Username'],
    hasAllKeys = checkFields.every({}.hasOwnProperty.bind(object));

console.log(hasAllKeys);
```

Comment: Unnecessary overcomplication with `{}.hasOwnProperty.bind(object)`, imo.